# In C, can you do this? int i; i = get_long() % 20;

Tags: c, types, implicit-conversion

```
unsigned long get_long(); //returns some crazy large unsigned long

int i; 

i = get_long() % 20;
```

The value of the right hand side should ALWAYS be big enough to fit into an integer because the possible values are only {0, 1, 2 .... 18, 19}.

Can I assume that the compiler can convert that `unsigned long` right hand side to an integer on the left hand side?

Comment: What is `get_long`? It is no standard function. See [ask]

Comment: `big enough to fit into an integer`...what?

Comment: @WeatherVane poor formatting.

Comment: get_long() is just an arbitrary prototype for a function that returns an unsigned long.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextras -Wconversions`) and see.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh I see you edited as I commented will delete.

Comment: If get_long() is something you had defined before that is working, there is no reason for you to not be able to use it in an expression. So what you wrote is valid. C allows implicit downcast between integral types.

Comment: If the values returned by `getLong()` are certain to always be in the range [0 ... 380], then why, other than its name, would you declare its value to be of type `unsigned long`?  `unsigned int` would be a better fit, or even `unsigned short`.

Comment: @John Bollinger you are right, that was unnecessary on my part

Comment: Why all those downvotes?

Comment: @alk I think the get_long() prototype was confusing to some people.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the compiler will perform implicit *conversion* (not cast) from the `unsigned long int` to `int`, because in your case `int` is a target type of the `=` assignment operator.

The `INT_MAX` is always at least of `32767`, so values from `[0, 19]` are to be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the compiler is conforming to the standard.

[N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers, paragraph 1 says:

> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if
>   the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.

According to N1570 5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types <limits.h>, `int` can store at least all integers from -32767 to 32767, conversion of integer in range of 0 to 19 to `int` is safe.